# AzureAD B2C - SAML LogoutRequest are not signed

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

We have a custom policy that federates to an ADFS IDP (using SAML). Login works fine. But logout is failing or ignored.

ADFS is logging an error in it's eventlog:

```
MSIS7084: SAML logout request and logout response messages must be signed when using SAML HTTP Redirect or HTTP POST binding.
```

Viewing the GET request built by B2C, it is indeed missing a Signature. It not a query parameter nor in the saml body.

Signatures **are** being sent for the login requests (as query parameters).

Here's the metadata settings for the Claims Provider:

```
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="IssuerUri">https://ourissuer</Item>
            <Item Key="PartnerEntity">metadata removed for brevity</Item>
            <Item Key="XmlSignatureAlgorithm">Sha256</Item>
            <Item Key="ResponsesSigned">true</Item>
            <Item Key="WantsSignedRequests">true</Item>
            <Item Key="WantsSignedAssertions">true</Item>
            <Item Key="WantsEncryptedAssertions">false</Item>
            <Item Key="IdpInitiatedProfileEnabled">true</Item>
            <Item Key="IncludeClaimResolvingInClaimsHandling">true</Item>
            <Item Key="SingleLogoutEnabled">true</Item>
          </Metadata>
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: Have you attempted to configure the app manifest and the app metadata endpoint? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/saml-service-provider?tabs=windows&pivots=b2c-custom-policy#override-or-set-the-logout-url-optional

Comment: I've trying to use ADFS as an external identity provider. This is configured within the custom policy as a ClaimsProvider. The login request are signed correctly, but the signature is missing for logout

Comment: following https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-adfs-saml?tabs=windows&pivots=b2c-custom-policy and using <Item Key="WantsSignedRequests">true</Item>

Answer (score 0):

In order to validate the application , certification should be specified in the ADFS application properties section.
I tried below steps to resolve the reported issue.
Please follow below steps:

1. Open ADFS
2. Expand servers
3. Select the required application
4. Right click on the application to select properties
5. Choose signature category and verify If the certificate is trusted and make sure it is not expired.

[image]

6. Your   SignAuthnRequest must also be set to true

   `<PartnerIdentityProvider Name="https://ExampleIdentityProvider" SignAuthnRequest="true"`

[image]

Comment: @solidstore was this resolved ? . Am facing a similar issue